# Ndk-build: CreateProcess: make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c++, windows, android-ndk, createprocess

I get an error when build static lib with NDK on Windows platform:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess( "PATH"\android-ndk-r8b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ar.exe, "some other commands" ) failed.
make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/staticlib.a] Error 87
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

All source files build successfully, and this error occur when compose object files.

I don't get this error when build this project in Ubuntu, it occur only on Windows.

I suppose I found the **issue**: second parameter of [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) Win API function *lpCommandLine* has max length **32,768** characters. But in my case it is more than 32,768 characters.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 36):

Maybe the `LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS` flag, to be set in your Android.mk, could help you. It is designed to overcome the limitations on the number of characters a Windows command can handle.

According to $(NDK folder)/docs/ANDROID-MK.html:

> LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS
>
> Set this variable to 'true' when your module has a very high number of
>      sources and/or dependent static or shared libraries. This forces the
>      build system to use an intermediate list file, and use it with the
>      library archiver or static linker with the @$(listfile) syntax.
>
> This can be useful on Windows, where the command-line only accepts
>      a maximum of 8191 characters, which can be too small for complex
>      projects.
>
> This also impacts the compilation of individual source files, placing
>      nearly all compiler flags inside list files too.
>
> Note that any other value than 'true' will revert to the default
>      behaviour. You can also define APP_SHORT_COMMANDS in your
>      Application.mk to force this behaviour for all modules in your
>      project.
>
> NOTE: We do not recommend enabling this feature by default, since it
>            makes the build slower.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 22):

Special Thanks to @mbrenon !

> Remember to set both of LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS(Android.mk) & APP_SHORT_COMMANDS(Application.mk) as the following.

```
LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true
APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true
```

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: can we add these lines on the top of others ? and i have multiple adroid.mk files should i add this command in all those files ?

Comment: According to the docs: `You can also define APP_SHORT_COMMANDS in your Application.mk to force this behaviour for all modules in your project`.

Comment: And the `LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS` variable should be placed after the `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` line.

Answer (score 1):

I  was facing same problem and it got resolved when I made below changes

1. Right click Application -> properties
2. C/C++ Build
3. Changed
   Build directory: ${workspace_loc:/App}/Default 
   to
   ${workspace_loc:/App}/

Comment: There's a character limit, and you shortened the character length of your paths. It's not surprising this would work for you, but is a pretty obvious workaround for paths being too long.