# Error while compiling android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

While compiling cpp files using command prompt iam getting the following error

make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect.

Any idea how to resolve this error.. iam using android-ndk-r9c.

Comment: The error itself saying na, parameter is incorrect. So please check all your parameter types in your code.

Comment: @saa in which file it does not give any info about files or anything, there must be problem with ndk or something..

Comment: check this link once.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598933/ndk-build-createprocess-make-e-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect

Comment: @saa already tried that.. but no use

Comment: Ok... enable log. so you can find out line number. To enable it just add NDK_LOG=1 in your command

Comment: you should post a snapshot from the code you are having the error. it might even be a syntax error you made in your parameter when calling the function.

Comment: solved it by adding LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS  := true at android.mk