# Android tess-two ndk-build keeps failing with 'Error 87' on libtess.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I have been trying to compiling the tess-two project for android but it keeps failing.

I have tried chaning the 'command' like this
    `commandLine 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r10e', '-C', 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Android_Studio\Projects\tess-two-master\eyes-two\src\main'
    commandLine 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r12b', '-C', 'C:\Users\\Documents\Android_Studio\Projects\tess-two-master\eyes-two\src\main'`

As with this I have tried two versions of NDK as well, I have downloaded the latest version of tess-two.
I have tried compiling the libraries directly but I also get the same error:
    `` make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect.
    make: *** [C:/Users/JuanS/Documents/Android_Studio/Projects/tess-two-master/tess-two/obj/local/armeabi/libtess.so] Error 87
    make: Leaving directory `C:/Users/JuanS/Documents/Android_Studio/Projects/tess-two-master/tess-two/jni' ``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ndk-build: CreateProcess: make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598933/ndk-build-createprocess-make-e-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you intend to call ndk-build here, this command should look like this instead:

```
commandLine 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r12b\ndk-build.cmd',
'-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
```

The `absolutePath` method will return the absolute path to your project with that relative path appended, effectively giving you the same path as you're using now. It's just a bit less annoying as you don't need to update it if you decide to rename or move your project.

Looks like you're on Windows, so make sure to call `ndk-build.cmd` instead of `ndk-build`.