# Running telegram messaging project in android studio, can't fix errors

Tags: android, telegram

I am not able to find any appropriate solution for below issue. I just want to run telegram messaging app in my android studio. I already obtained the neccesary data from telegram like api_id and api_hash, and put it in BuildVars.java. Now I m getting 2 errors, which I cant solve a few days.

Errors are:
1)

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug'.
>
> > Build command failed. Error while executing 'C:\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with
> >     arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> >     APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
> >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk
> >     APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDEBUG=1
> >     APP_PLATFORM=android-14
> >     NDK_OUT=D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj
> >     NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib
> >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14
> >     D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.24.so}
> >     [armeabi-v7a] "Compile arm    ": "tmessages.24 <= opus.c"
> >     process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
> >     C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o.d
> >     -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -O2 -DNDEBUG -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
> >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures
> >     -ID:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict= -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DLIBYUV_NEON -DLIBYUV_NEON -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
> >     -c D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus.c
> >     -o D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o,
> >     ...) failed. make (e=2): ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.   make: ***
> >     [D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o]
> >     Error 2

2)

> Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
>   use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o.d
>   -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -O2 -DNDEBUG -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
>   -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures
>   -ID:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict= -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DLIBYUV_NEON -DLIBYUV_NEON -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
>   -c D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus.c
>   -o D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o,
>   ...) failed. make (e=2): ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
>
> make: ***
>   [D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o]
>   Error 2
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug'.
>
>   > Build command failed. Error while executing 'C:\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with
>   >     arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   >     APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
>   >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk
>   >     APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDEBUG=1
>   >     APP_PLATFORM=android-14
>   >     NDK_OUT=D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj
>   >     NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\AndroidProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib
>   >     NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14
>   >     D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.24.so}
>   >     [armeabi-v7a] "Compile arm    ": "tmessages.24 <= opus.c"
>   >     process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
>   >     C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o.d
>   >     -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -g -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -O2 -DNDEBUG -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward
>   >     -IC:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures
>   >     -ID:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict= -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DLIBYUV_NEON -DLIBYUV_NEON -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -isystem C:/android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
>   >     -c D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus.c
>   >     -o D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o,
>   >     ...) failed. make (e=2): ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.   make: ***
>   >     [D:/AndroidProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/tmessages.24/./opus/src/opus.o]
>   >     Error 2
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

P.S. I'm using 2.2.1 gradle version. I tried to run ndk-build.cmd from command line, with NDK_PROJECT_PATH and NDK_APPLICATION_MK, didn't get any result. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This solution works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598933/ndk-build-createprocess-make-e-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect